# How to put the height of a div that contains other with absolute position?

Tags: html, css

How to put the height of a div that contains other with absolute position?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.a{

}
.b{
position:relative;
}
.c{
position:absolute;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="a">
<div class="b">
<div class="c">
   ESTO ES LO QUE CONTIENE EL DIV<br/>
   ESTO ES LO QUE CONTIENE EL DIV<br/>
   ESTO ES LO QUE CONTIENE EL DIV<br/>
   ESTO ES LO QUE CONTIENE EL DIV<br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

The height of the div class "a" is zero

Comment: Why does `c` need to be positioned absolutely? If you change its  position (i.e. modify its `top` and `left` styles), are you expecting `a` and `b` to change in size and/or position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An absolutely positioned element does not take up any space in the layout, meaning that `<div class='a'>` won't expand to wrap it.

The only way you could possibly do this is to measure the height of `.c` via javascript and then set height of `.a` explicitly -- the downside, of course, is requiring javascript to do so.

Depending on where you are trying to position `.c` you may want to consider using a float instead, which CAN be wrapped.

Comment: Sounds like floating elements is what he needs indeed. Using JS is going to be big headache...

Answer (score 0):

it will not matter if you give DIV B a height smaller than DIV C , because DIV C can over lap its container.

sorry if I didn't get the question right

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` or any other block-container will automatically grow vertically according to the content, but once you `position:absolute` any `<div>`, you are removing it from its parent content and no longer makes its parent expands.

You might want to try to float the `<div class="c">` instead of absolutely position it. That way the div will continue to be part of its parent content, though you would have to set the `<div class="a">` to `overflow:auto` in order to make it expand on floated elements.